# Appending to object inside of anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I am trying to append the results of a db query to a table like so:

```
function foo() {
    var result = {};

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Problem establishing connection with the database");
            return;
        }

        var tables = ["first", "second", "third"];

        _.forEach(tables, function(table) {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM " + table;

            connection.query(query, function(err, data) {
                if(!err) {
                    result[table] = data;
                } else {
                    console.log("Problem performing query \"%s\"", query);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    return result;
}
```

The returned result is empty, but inside of the `forEach`, it is being populated. I can prove this by adding a log message in the loop.

I can only think this is a scoping problem but when I changed result to a property (`this.result`) and tried to assign to that from in the loop I get the same results. I made sure I was using the correct instance of `this` by adding `var that = this;` at the start of the function and assigning to `that.result` inside of the loop.

Comment: Is this sql call synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a scoping problem, it's a timing problem.

You're trying to return `result` *before* `result` is filled in, because your code inside the anonymous function doesn't run until after your `foo` function returns. It's *asynchronous*. I expect the `query` calls are asynchronous as well.

Since `foo` relies on something asynchronous to do its work, it cannot *return* the result. It has to do what `getConnection` and `query` do: Accept a callback function that it will call, later, with the result.

Here's one way you might do that, see the code comments:

```
function foo(callback) { // <== Note `callback`

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Problem establishing connection with the database");
            callback(null); // Do the callback, with a flag value for failure
            return;
        }

        var tables = ["first", "second", "third"];
        var result = {};
        var results = 0; // Remember how many results we've seen
        _.forEach(tables, function(table) {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM " + table;

            connection.query(query, function(err, data) {
                if(!err) {
                    result[table] = data;
                } else {
                    console.log("Problem performing query \"%s\"", query);
                    result[table] = null; // Flag value for failure
                }
                if (++results === tables.length) {
                    // We're done, issue the callback
                    callback(results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the query functions are asynchronous, when the code first runs through, it sends off the queries, then returns your blank object because the queries have not returned yet.

When the queries do return, the properties of that object should be filled out, but you will need to have some code to run at that time in order to "see" it. If you are expecting your code to return the populated object from that function, you will be disappointed. :-)